# Parsing html using jsdom and jquery on nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, jsdom

```
<td class="main1">
<br>
<img width="519" height="768" alt="2011 New Year styles, in better quality!" src="http://www.causewaymall.com/shop/images/J-1045.5.jpg">
<br>
<img width="500" height="752" alt="2011 New Year styles, in better quality!" src="http://www.causewaymall.com/shop/images/T-3378.jpg">
</td>
```

how the code to get url image with nodejs? ex :
this my code :

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var url = 'http://www.causewaymall.com/shop/-i-163.html';
jsdom.env(url,
    [
        'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
    ],
    function(errors, window) {
        console.log("Url Image : =>  " + window.$(".main1 img").attr("src"));
    });
```

please tell me mr.

Comment: What does it print at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

If your html looks something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="main1">
      <br>
      <img width="519" height="768" alt="2011 New Year styles, in better quality!" src="http://hmm.jpg">
      <br>
      <img width="500" height="752" alt="2011 New Year styles, in better quality!" src="http://hmm2.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You should be able to extract the img src using:

```
window.$('.main1').find('img').attr('src');
```